# how to check in an XMLTree if it and return

Tags: java, xml, recursion

I'm having trouble being able to figure out why this is giving the incorrect value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleReader in = new SimpleReader1L();
    SimpleWriter out = new SimpleWriter1L();
    boolean x = true;
    out.print("Enter a URL or file name for an XML source: ");
    String url = in.nextLine();
    XMLTree xml = new XMLTree2(url);
    out.print("Enter the name of a tag: ");
    String tag = in.nextLine();
    out.println(findTag(xml, tag));
}

/**
 * Reports whether the given tag appears in the given {@code XMLTree}.
 * 
 * @param xml
 *            the {@code XMLTree}
 * @param tag
 *            the tag name
 * @return true if the given tag appears in the given {@code XMLTree}, false
 *         otherwise
 * @ensures <pre>
 * findTag =
 *    [true if the given tag appears in the given {@code XMLTree}, false otherwise]
 * </pre>
 */
private static boolean findTag(XMLTree xml, String tag) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (xml.isTag()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < xml.numberOfChildren(); i++) {

            findTag(xml.child(i), tag);
            System.out.println("label is " + xml.label());
            if (xml.label().equals(tag)) {
                result = true;
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

when given an xml tree the code runs so that it finds all of the tags that is present in the tree. It compares every single tag to the tag being searched. How would I make it so that when the given tag is found in the XML it updates the boolean variable and stops it from searching for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do what you want.

1). Make the `boolean` variable as static global variable to the method.

2). Pass the `boolean` variable to the `method` as an `argument`.
 Before processing the method just check the state of the variable.

Something like this

```
private static boolean findTag(XMLTree xml, String tag,boolean result) {       
    if (xml.isTag() && !result) {
        for (int i = 0; i < xml.numberOfChildren(); i++) {

            findTag(xml.child(i), tag,result);
            System.out.println("label is " + xml.label());
            if (xml.label().equals(tag)) {
                result = true;
                System.out.println(result);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```